# NHibernate 3, Dynamic-Component, Dictionaries, and LINQ Queries

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I've got this entity with a `<dynamic-component>` entry and a number of 
properties on it. It's being consumed on the entity class as an 
`IDictionary`.

The mapping works fine and everything is hunky dory until 
I go to query based on values in this dictionary.

First I tried the following linq query:

```
repository.Where(x => x.Specifications[key] == value)
```

To query against it. (Specifications is the dynamic component) The 
query resulted in the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Type.ComponentType' to type 
>   'NHibernate.Type.CollectionType'.

Figuring this might be outside the bounds of the Linq Provider I then 
went on to build a `BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod` to handle a custom linq 
extension for it.

It was built up by using the `treeBuilder.Dot(...)` AST like this:

```
var specificationExpression = 
  treeBuilder.Dot( 
     visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(), 
     treeBuilder.Ident("Specifications")).AsExpression(); 
var targetExpression = 
  treeBuilder.Dot( 
    visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(), 
    treeBuilder.Ident(keyExpression.Value.ToString())).AsExpression();
```

This worked great for generating the right SQL except that the 
expression is cached so subsequent calls to this function would 
compare all the values against the first key.

From here I found the `treeBuilder.DictionaryItem(...)` AST Node and 
built the following:

```
var specificationExpression = 
  treeBuilder.Dot( 
     visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(), 
     treeBuilder.Ident("Specifications")).AsExpression(); 
var specification = 
  treeBuilder.DictionaryItem(specificationExpression, key).AsExpression();
```

Once again I was met with the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast 
>   object of type 'NHibernate.Type.ComponentType' to type 
>   'NHibernate.Type.CollectionType'.

---

**The Question**

What am I doing wrong here? Can `<dynamic-component>`' s not be queried on? Am I implementing this incorrectly? Could this be a bug I should report?

Mapping:

```
<dynamic-component name="Specifications"> 
  <property name="sp_Graphics" column="sp_Graphics" /> 
  <property name="sp_Weight" column="sp_Weight" /> 
</dynamic-component>
```

Entity:

```
/// <summary> 
/// Specifications 
/// </summary> 
public virtual IDictionary Specifications { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to a bug in the NHibernate linq provider you will not be able to use it to query dynamic components as of 3.1.0

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2664

Here is hoping that a fix can be worked out for version 3.2

In the meantime you should use a Criteria or HQL query.

Answer (score 4):

It's fixed since NHibernate 3.3.1 (valid link here : https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2664)